# How to Pause Render by Clicking Draver?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In the following example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-lumiere-8uct78

You will see that when you click on Draver on the left side and select Home every time you open Draver  component Home render (you can see in the console) is there a way to pause this processing?

I would be happy to answer any further questions you may have
Thanks for any reply

Comment: I am not sure about "pausing" but with the useMemo hook, you can prevent components from rerendering if non of their props have changed and non of their defined states vars have changed.

Comment: I tried to use with memo and failed you can please give me an example how to use with it?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much to anyone who wanted to help I got along I used with memo
Anyone who encounters this issue as well can go into the sandbox I shared above and see what I have changed
Attached is a simple example of how to use with memo:

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
const Home = () => {
return (
<div>
  Home
</div>
);
};

export default memo(Home);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).